# Если размер больше то выводим переменную

Tags: php

```
 $w1 = "<script>document.write(screen.width)</script>";
        $fst = (int) $w1;
        $str = 991;
        $str1 = (int) $str;
        if($fst >= $str1){
            echo $search;
        }else{
            echo "Не выводим";
        }
```

Если размер больше чем 991 то выводим переменную search
Не пойму в чем проблема

Comment: @entithat в моей ситуации это единственное глупое решение которое мне подойдет. Мне нужно если размер окна больше чем 991 px то вы выводим переменную

Comment: Да, ну это я понял, но ведь `$w1` возвратит 0.. Здесь никак не можно сугубо использовать php... Вам стоит переписать на js

Comment: Нет, это решение Вам не подойдет. Потому что это не *решение*, а черт знает что.

Comment: "Не пойму в чем ..." - в том, что `$w1` это строка в серверном коде, равная тому, что справа от знака `=`.

Comment: `if (window.innerWidth < 991) { console.log('<?= $variable ?>'); }` - вот так примерно должно было бы быть.